# ImageMagick, Can ImageMagick return single annotation as a bitmap?

Tags: bitmap, annotations, return, imagemagick

Can imagemagick return a single annotation as a bitmap. Magick draw annotation on the image directly, which I need is a bitmap just exactly contains the annotation.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the annotation and no background, you presumably need a transparent background so you can later overlay the annotation on another image. In that case, you need to store it in a format that supports transparency, such as PNG, so use:

```
convert -background transparent -pointsize  32 -fill blue label:"I am on a transparent background" text.png
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much, I did what like you said, but I still need to calculate the size of the background, I used to think ImageMagick has provided an API like this, but now I'll make one myself.